How to decompose a given polynomial by ideal generators
Given a finite set of polynomials $f_1, f_2,..., f_n$ of variables $x_1,...,x_m$, generating the ideal $I$, suppose that we have one more polynomial $g\in I$.
What is the algorythm for decomposing $g$ w.r.t set of $f_i$?
Namely representing $g=h_1 f_1+... h_n f_n$

Not sure if this is the best way, but we can compute a Grobner basis $B$ of $I$, expressing its generators in terms of $f_i$. Any $g\in I$ reduces to $0$ w.r.t. $B$, which gives a representation of $g$ in terms of polynomials in $B$, which then translates into a representation of $g$ in terms of $f_i$.

ADDED. Here is a more transparent way at the cost of adding a new variable $y_i$ for each $f_i$. Let $B'$ be a Grobner basis of $\langle f_i-y_i\rangle$ w.r.t. the elimination order weighting $x$'s more than $y$'s. Then a polynomial $g\in I$ reduces w.r.t. $B'$ to a polynomial $h(y_1,\dots,y_n)$ with coefficients being polynomials in $x$'s and $h(0,\dots,0)=0$, giving the required representation $g=h(f_1,\dots,f_n)$.

Actually I have a related question. How can we decompose Grobner basis elements in terms of $f_i$ using only Grobner algorythm as a blackbox and not looking inside. I heard about introducing dummy variables for each original polynomial. Just in case, could you elaborate on this? Because in Sympy, "groebner" function does that, but it does not provide actual decomposition, only gives the basis itself.

@DmitriScheglov: Yes, dummy variables can be used for that purpose. However, if you are willing to introduce them, you can directly solve the original problem - see update in my answer.

from your updated answer it follows that $g$ in fact lies in the ring, generated by $f_i$, not just the ideal. Can you clarify it please?

@DmitriScheglov: By construction, the free term of the polynomial $h$ is zero (if I got your concern correctly).

I mean that in general, $g$ does not necessarily belong to a ring , generated by $f_i$. And the very fact of existence of such $h$ implies that it does. This is my concern.

@DmitriScheglov: Ok. Second take - the coefficients of $h$ are polynomials in $x_i$. For example, for $n=1$, $f_1=x^2$ and $g=x^3$, we have $h=xy_1$, giving $g=xf_1$. Does that address your concern?

Oh I see. Couple more things. 1) is the requirement that dummy variables are lexicografically smaller  is the only order requirement? 2) If $g$ in fact does belong to the ring( which I highly suspect is the case in my situation, will it automatically imply that the polynomial $h$ will have constant coeefficients in terms of $x_i$ ?

@DmitriScheglov: 1) More or less. What you want from the monomial order is that in the reduction of $g$ it should eliminate all terms with just $x$'s (and so they have to be heavier than those with just $y$'s) to get the needed $h(0,\dots,0)=0$. At the same time you may compare $x$'s among themselves and $y$'s among themselves as you like. See link to the elimination (block) order in Wikipedia that I added to my answer.

That was clear enough, thank you!

And the 2 issue?

@DmitriScheglov: 2) Yes, it will since the polynomial purely depending on $y$'s is smaller than any polynomial involving at least one $x$. So, if a polynomial in just $y$'s exists, $h$ will be it.

No more questions so far, thank you!
